# Continuous database insert with Node.js and MySQL (Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I need to steadily insert values into a database. I've tried with this code:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
const random = require("random");

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "xxx",
  user: "xxx",
  password: "xxx",
  database: "xxx"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  while (true) {
    if (err) throw err;
    val1_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
    val2_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
    val3_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
    val4_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
    var sql =
      "INSERT INTO Table (val1, val2, val3, val4)VALUES (" +
      val1_ +
      "," +
      val2_ +
      "," +
      val3_ +
      "," +
      val4_ +
      ")";
    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }
});
```

but I get this **Error: `Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.`** I know this is not probably the way to do this task, it's just to make you understand what I want to do. How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: Seems like a scenario where you might want to use connection pooling. See: (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1213)

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when successive `connection.connect()` are called. Here you should be good with removing the intial `con.connect()` because `con.query()` would implicitly establish a connection.

See **Establishing connections** section [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#readme)

```
 while (true) {
  val1_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
  val2_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
  val3_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
  val4_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
  var sql =
    "INSERT INTO Table (val1, val2, val3, val4)VALUES (" +
    val1_ +
    "," +
    val2_ +
    "," +
    val3_ +
    "," +
    val4_ +
    ")";
  con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}
```

For multi-inserts (**Above is not a good way to do it**), suggest **you collect the data and do it with a single insert:**

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO Table(val1, val2, val3, val4) VALUES ? `;
let valsArray = [];
//while must have a terminating condition for that query to get executed/reached

    while (true) {
      val1_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
      val2_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
      val3_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
      val4_ = random.int((min = 0), (max = 100));
      valsArray.push([val1_, val2_, val3_, val4_]);
    }
    //notice valsArray would be an array of array values
    connection.query(sql, [valsArray], (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
      // get inserted rows
      console.log("Row inserted:" + results.affectedRows);
    });
```

**NOTE:** More details for successive connections error in one of their [test suites](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/49939c525725e13067356faf73ec557d6c526e13/test/unit/connection/test-double-connect.js)

Comment: unfortunately now i'm getting this error: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Comment: @giulioPiva Just to confirm, did you replace that `while(true)` with a correct terminating condition coz that is an infinite loop. If yes, how much data are you gathering in the memory with that while.

Answer (score 0):

In your **app.js** or similar main application file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
  user: process.env.DB_USER || 'local_user',
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'local_password',
  database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'local_database'
});

global.db = connection;
// access the pool of connection anywhere without 
// additional require or module.exports
```

**my_tasks.js** or elsewhere in your application where insert is executed

```
const random = require('random');

// define the query, ? is a placeholder for object to be inserted
let sql = "INSERT INTO table_name SET ?;";


// begin your while loop if needed

//define object to be inserted where keys match table field names and values are your values
let payload = {
  val1_: random.int((min = 0), (max = 100)),
  val2_: random.int((min = 0), (max = 100)),
  val3_: random.int((min = 0), (max = 100)),
  val4_: random.int((min = 0), (max = 100)),
}

db.query(sql, payload, function(error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results);
});
// end your loop
```

I'm not sure what it is you're testing for in your `while` loop but it can be applied in this second code block as needed.

Comment: if i put my_task.js code into a while(true) block, this error comes out: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory.
However, i solved using setInterval

Comment: @giulioPiva You don't need `setInterval` and of course `while(true)` because that is essentially an infinite loop. Just putting a limiting condition on while should do it

Comment: As @ ambianBeing mentions, it seems like your `while` loop might be exceeding the  available resources to support it. If you would like to update your example with details specific to the `loop` (how long does it run, how many iterations per period, when does `true` become `false`), why you need it, and your desired outcome, we can provide further advice. It seems like your goal might just be load testing, in which case I would recommend something like http://locust.io over code looping.